# Siemens ME45 phone do not respond on AT-commands on serial port

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command

I connected Siemens ME45 to a Arduino Leonardo as shown here:

[image: scheme]

Phone reacts on AT-commands from Arduino, it makes a call, send SMS, but it don't give any feedback on Serial Port Monitor. For example it should return "0" or "1" when asked by command "AT+CMGF=?". Nothing happens. What can be a cause?

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define rxPin 0
#define txPin 1

SoftwareSerial mySerial(rxPin,txPin); // RX, TX

void setup(){

    pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Arduino serial initialized!");
    delay(1000);

    mySerial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Software serial initialized!");
    delay(1000);

}

void loop(){

    issueCommand("AT+CMGF=?");
    readSerial();
    delay(200);

    while(true){
        readSerial();
    }
}

void issueCommand(char* msg){
    mySerial.println(msg);
    Serial.print(msg);
    delay(10);
}

void readSerial(){
    while (mySerial.available()){
        Serial.println(mySerial.read());
        delay(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using software serial on hardware serial pins? Why not just use hardware serial?

Comment: Can't say why. I use code from: https://michaelrogger.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/interfacing-an-at-command-capable-phone-sony-ericsson-t610-with-arduino-and-incoming-call-number-identification/

Comment: That code uses pins 10 and 11.